# Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError. Something went wrong with react and babel

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack, babeljs

I have some problems with React using Django.
Everything was fine, until i wrote some text using cyrillic letters right into my react component code.
Then i get this error in chrome console:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\src\components\createroompage.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (43:20)

[0m [90m 41 | [39m        }[0m
[0m [90m 42 | [39m[0m
[0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 43 | [39m        [33mОСТАНОВИЛСЯ[39m [33mНА[39m [33mТОМ[39m [33mЧТО[39m [33mПОЛУЧАЮ[39m [33mBAD[39m [33mREQUEST[39m [33mНА[39m [33mМОИ[39m [33mКЛЮЧ[39m [33m-[39m [33mЗНАЧНИЕ[39m[0m
[0m [90m    | [39m                    [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[0m [90m 44 | [39m[0m
[0m [90m 45 | [39m        fetch([32m'api/crapiview'[39m[33m,[39m requestOptions)[33m;[39m[0m
[0m [90m 46 | [39m    }[0m
    at Object._raise (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:748:17)
    at Object.raiseWithData (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:741:17)
    at Object.raise (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:735:17)
    at Object.unexpected (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9097:16)
    at Object.semicolon (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9079:40)
    at Object.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12190:10)
    at Object.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11786:19)
    at Object.parseStatement (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11650:17)
    at Object.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12232:25)
    at Object.parseBlockBody (C:\Users\Lenovo B590\Documents\DEV\React-DDJ.TWT\music_controller\frontend\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12218:10)
    at eval (webpack://frontend/./src/components/createroompage.js?:1:7)
    at Object../src/components/createroompage.js (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/main.js:2:4127)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/main.js:2:251468)
    at eval (webpack://frontend/./src/components/homepage.js?:6:73)
    at Object../src/components/homepage.js (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/main.js:2:7470)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/main.js:2:251468)
    at eval (webpack://frontend/./src/components/app.js?:6:67)
    at Object../src/components/app.js (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/main.js:2:2509)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/main.js:2:251468)
    at eval (webpack://frontend/./src/index.js?:2:76)
```

Obviously its due to cyrillic letters, so i deleted it. Then i tryed to refresh the page and i got the same error. Finally i even deleted all the code in src\components\createroompage.js file, then saved it and even turned off my pc, and anyway i`m getting the same error above.

**So the questions is:** how is it possible (there is no code in the file at all not saying about cyrillic letters)? how to fix it?
Seems like babel works incorrect: (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js).

**My settings:**

*babel.config.json*

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.10.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helped, but anyway thx for suggestion, @Zargold.
Obviuously its something with cache and babel, rimaf didnt helped, to clear npm cache manually too.
What helped is to delete all node_modules in the frontend app and json/js configurations files too. Then reinstall it manually. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by clearing the cache. however, when you open the node_modules and there is a .cache folder when deleting that then you don't have to worry about deleting your whole node_modules. when it is deleted and you restart the project the folder gets regenerated but empty